# Is java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream's output byte array portable?

Tags: compression, gzip

I've this following code to serialize and compress a String:

```
private byte[] toZip(String xml) {
    try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gz = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(gz);
        oos.writeObject(xml);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e){
        log.error("Error", e);
        if(log.isEnabledFor(MucamLogger.FINEST))log.finest(xml);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Are the returned byte[] portable?. I store it on a blob field on the data base. Could it be retrieved and decompress with any non-Java program (C++, .Net)?.  Do this non-Java program recover the original String text?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gzip streams are portable and the original uncompressed data will be recovered exactly. Assuming of course that you are faithfully transporting the binary compressed data. I often see that get messed up due to end-of-line conversions or unicode text conversions that could be easily avoided.